# C# Linq2Sql GroupBy without Aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following table

```
Login  Permission
user1      A      
user1      B      
user2      A      
user2      B
```

and I want to have the following output:

```
user1 A,B
user2 A,B
```

to do so, I use the GroupBy method

```
var results = (from p in  _dbContext.Users
               group p by new { p.Login } into g
                select new { Login = g.Key.Login, 
                             Permissions = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Permission)).ToList()
```

but without any aggregate function the given code fails. How to fix it ?

Comment: by default `group by` requires to have an `aggregate` function in the `select` query, but in that case I don't need any `aggregate` function, so that's the issue

Comment: LINQ to SQL would work, so are you using LINQ to EF 6.x/EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5?

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard SQL way to concatenate strings as a grouping function, hence there's no support for doing so in Linq2Sql.

You can, however, use in-memory Linq by using `AsEmumerable()` to swicth the processing from Linq2Sql to in-memory Linq:

```
var results = (from p in  _dbContext.Users.AsEnumerable()
               group p by new { p.Login } into g
               select new { Login = g.Key.Login, 
                         Permissions = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Permission)).ToList();
```

Note that this pulls the entire `Users` table into memory in order to do the joining, but unless your users table is massive it shouldn't be a huge problem. If it *is*, then you could look at some SQL tricks to do string concatenation and either tunr it into a stored procedure to call from Linq or pass in a custom SQL query. But you're not going to be able to do it with Linq functionality alone.

Comment: Actually, LINQ to SQL handles this just fine - it converts into a SQL `GROUP BY` query on `p.Login` and then runs individual queries for each group for the columns in the `Select` (`x.Permission`). It is LINQ to EF 6.x/EF Core 3.x/5 that is unable to translate it.